# How to add github-resident single-file header library to Visual Studio C++ solution/project?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, solution

I've been away from VS for some years and am now returning and would like to make use of modern integrations, e.g., github.

Given my own project, in a VC++ solution/project, how do I most *effectively* add single-file header libraries from public github repositories?

1. Is there a way to do it directly as a dependency given the url of the repo?
2. Do I clone it locally and add it as a dependency?
3. Do I clone it locally and add the header file to the solution/project
4. `vcpkg`?
5. Some use of git's submodules (integrated with VS I hope...)?
6. Or?

I'd like it to show up in my project in such a way that I can do `#include "best-json/best-json.hpp"` for a file in the `someuser\best-json` repository on GitHub.  (Or GitLab, or anywhere with a url.)

- I'd like that to be the case even if, in the remote repository, the header file in question was in a subdirectory under the root called `include`, or maybe a subdirectory called `best-json`, or maybe even at top level.

By "*effectively*" I mean: Does the "right" thing as described above, even though not necessarily the absolute simplest way to do it.

Perhaps there's a VS extension that automates this?

[I searched the web for this but only found pages talking about how I'd export ("publish" I guess) my project to Github, or how to clone an entire project from Github, etc. etc.]